# Look for a value a cell above

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, difference

I'm looking for a formula or a VBA code for the following problem.

I need to get the total operational hours in a  day (J). This is de difference from the start-up time (I) and the shutdown time (K) over the whole day.

Most of the entries are 2 a day, but as you can see in the picture this one has 4. Previously I had the formula in J : `=IF(K49="";0;IF(EXACT(A49;A48);(K49-I48);(K49-I49)))` But with 4 entries this does not work anymore (the A49 and A28 are just numbers if they are the same it means that it is the same day)

So where I'm basically looking for is that it will take the shut downtime and looks for the first value in I and that it is calculating the difference in J.

[image]

Comment: Can you better explain what "with 4 entries this does not work anymore" means?

Comment: Like on the picture, there are 4 entries. At the first entry, the machine is started up and the last entry the machine is shut down. Most of the time we perform 2 tasks with the machine but on this day it were 4, so 4 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to another cell can be done, using `OffSet(Row, Col)`. In case you need the cell just above, you use `OffSet(-1,0)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and it needs to do that until it finds a cell with a value. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use some nested IFs to check first the row above, then the one above that, then the one more above.
Something like this (sorry, I cannot embed images):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLHVO.png

Comment: Thank you this was where i was looking for :)